# Express js - Getting different string length than expected

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I'm trying to pass one string from POST request. consider like this.

```
{
  "phone": "11111111111"
}
```

Now in backend side with use of body parser, I can get this value by req.body.phone. Which I'm getting correctly.

But the string length of this variable is always 1 more than the actual one.
Now current examples value should be 11 in the console but I'm getting 12. because of that, comparison with static number is false. However static variable length gives me 11. I don't if this problem is with body parser library or some other issue.

How can solve this problem?

Comment: Can you share some code about how you exactly POST the data to the back-end and how do you handle it there? Nobody can help you without any information.

Comment: Print the variable, character by character, to your sever log and post the results.

Comment: @StevenSpungin Getting  extra empty string.

Comment: @parth So you are getting 2 strings, one empty?  Or an extra space?  Or maybe a newline is turning into a carriage_return/newline.  Dumping the char codes will help understand what is going on.  My bet is on the CRLF...

Comment: @StevenSpungin I'm using windows. So that means it writes extra character somehow? I'm not sure how to solve this

Comment: You can try to replace "\r" with "" in all your strings.  That might trim your string down to the expected length.  `str = str.replace(/\r/gm,'')`

Comment: Found something weird. This only happens when I use postman with variables inside. like {{host}}/message. If I do this then it's adding an extra string and if I use localhost:3000/message POST request then that's ok.